# React Native setTimeout performance

Tags: reactjs, react-native, settimeout

I have a react native component that has flatlist of 20 items (Data). The item contains component which uses setTimeout. Would this cause any performance

```
handleSpinner = result => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // handle task
    }, 3000);
    return<some stuff></some>
  };

  const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
    },

   //...MORE ITEMS
  ];

  <FlatList
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      data={list}
      renderItem={this.handleSpinner}
```

Comment: Considering setTimeout is non blocking all of the javascript should be able to be executed and you *shouldn't see any delay with the flatlist rendering. However creating potentially infinite setTimeout blocks will impact performance and likely slow things down. What are you trying to accomplish with setTimeout what task do you need to handle after 3 seconds?

Comment: I have text that blink however do not want to to blink into a time is reached. I discovered animated view as It has a delay prop

Answer (score 0):

It will cause the serious problem when there are lots of data in the list.

Comment: Any alternative methods to handle this